# MSAL acquisition of token silently is not working in IE 11 for React SPA

Tags: reactjs, authentication, internet-explorer, azure-ad-msal

For supporting IE 11, I'm including the following:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
```

Also disabled the protected mode in order to run the application locally (ref [Microsoft's Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-use-ie-browser))

Now I can log in and perform operations but the acquiring token silently is not working. I'm using local storage as cacheLocation and also found that everything is stored in local storage. But whenever I'm trying to acquire the token silently, I'm getting an error. After successful login if I close the browser and reopens the application in IE 11 then I expect that my application will acquire the token silently but it never happens in IE 11 (works fine in chrome & edge). It always fails to acquire the token silently with the following error:

```
InteractionRequiredAuthError: Silent authentication was denied. The user must first sign in and if needed grant the client application access to the scope 'user.read openid profile'.
```

In the browser console I get another error:

```
Error occurred in token received callback function. TypeError: Object expected.
```

Both of these errors only occur in IE 11 and works perfectly in chrome/edge.

Comment: whether you have added the reference to a promise polyfill (`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js" class="pre"></script>`) before referencing the MSAL.js script?

Comment: Besides, please check the IE browser setting, whether you set to delete the browser data when exit/close the browser instance. More detail see [this article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/manually-automatically-clear-browser-history/).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT: Thanks for your reply. I've checked IE browser setting and found that browser data is not deleted. Also confirmed that the cached authentication data is available on localStorage when I get the errors mentioned on this post.

react-app-polyfill supports promise and it's included before referencing the MSAL.js script. I believe it's working otherwise the normal authentication wouldn't have worked. What do you think?